# MS SQL Server 2016 In-Memory OLTP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, in-memory-tables, in-memory-oltp

I want to migrate a single table to be In-Memory, and I followed these steps:

1. Right click on the table
2. Select 'Memory Optimization Advisor'
3. Follow the wizard steps till the last step, then click 'Migrate'
4. The migration process doesn't complete and the following error appears

[image]

Comment: Presumably you have a DDL trigger that you need to temporarily disable

Comment: No, I don't have any kind of triggers

Comment: You almost certainly do. Check for *database* and *server* triggers, as per the error message, not triggers on the table `dbo.Attendance`. Look in `sys.triggers` and `sys.server_triggers`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I found a trigger created by redgate at the sys.server_triggers table.